# git: query regarding merging notes ref

Tags: git

The recommended approach for merging notes ref is

```
git checkout refs/notes/commits
git fetch origin refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/origin/commits
git notes merge -v origin/commits
git notes merge --commit
```

I tried this approach and it doesnt help to maintain a linear history. Below is the log which i got after performing the above steps.

```
*   857410f Merged notes from refs/notes/origin/commits into refs/notes/commits
|\
| *   1d6ff9e Merged notes from refs/notes/origin/commits into refs/notes/commits
| |\
| | * 18dec97 Notes added by 'git notes add'
| | * 2b7cfae Notes added by 'git notes add'
| | * 9e5e223 Notes added by 'git notes add'
| * 49ae944 Notes added by 'git notes add'
* 8f5fd8a Notes added by 'git notes add'
```

So my question is, is this the right approach of performing git notes merge. Please help out asap. Thanks.

Comment: If you are merging something, doesn't it mean that you have already lost the linearity?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `git notes merge` can only do true merges.

Is that the right approach? Well it seems like the simplest approach,
and how neat and tidy the commit log *for notes* looks [1] is
arguably much less important than for the regular commit log.

But if you want to use rebase instead:

```bash
git switch --detach notes/commits
git rebase notes/origin/commits
git update-ref refs/notes/commits @
git switch -q -
```

[full demo](https://pastebin.com/8gHtcqfy)

#### Notes

1. Obviously whether or not merges are “neat” is subjective